# separate git pull requests with different branches | How to git push a branch

Tags: git, github

I forked and cloned a repo to my local machine:

```
/sample_app
```

I want to submit 3 different pull requests to the original repo. As far as I can tell the way to do this is to create seperate pull requests from separate branches? I am confused as to the sequence of commands here.

I ran:

```
git checkout -b firstbranch
made changes... made changes..
git add .
git commit -m "finished first feature"
```

However when I run:

```
git push
```

I get:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

despite the fact that I just made a bunch of changes on my new branch(I can verify I am on new branch).

Am i supposed to run something other than `git push`? On my forked repo I still only see 1 master branch and no other branches.

After I push it from what I gather I would need to click on the pull request button and select that branch to submit through the pull request correct?

Then I can go to my command line and do:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b Secondbranch  ##To create a second branch for second feature
```

and repeat the process, etc

Am i getting this right?

How do I push my branch so that I can then create a branch specific pull request. Not merging it with main branch.

Comment: What does ruby on rails has to do with this question ? Please remove the tag .

Comment: Which version of Git? What does `git config push.default` return?

Answer (score 0):

Your process is right. You just need to do:

```
git push  <REMOTENAME> <BRANCHNAME>
```

See [here](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/)

Comment: Correct! Coz when you say just `git push` git pushes only matching branches and no new branch is pushed by default configuration.

Comment: I dont understand what to put in <REMOTENAME> or in <BRANCHNAME>. the upstream I forked from is owner/sample_app & my fork that I cloned is myname/sample_app. The branch I created on my clone is /firstbranch I want to push my branch up. How would I do it in this case? What is remote? and branch? for this?

Comment: Usually remote will be origin for remote repositories. And branch is the local branch you are working on. So you would do: git push origin firstbranch